# iOS: "Added to home screen" website won't refresh

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, webkit

I'm testing a website, and I usually open it in Safari iOS and then I add it to the homescreen so i can see it in full screen, this is my meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="favicon.png"/>  

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

but i noticed that when i reopen the app, sometimes, totally randomly the webapp won't refresh... i tried resetting safari, but nothign still the older version...

Is a strange behaviour i wonder if i shoudl set seomthing in the meta to forse the refresh at least for the debugging/test phase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wonder if this would work?

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

This link might help:

http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html